# Kaplan-Meier including survival and transplant data

Tags: r, survival-analysis

What I have is a Kaplan-Meier Analysis of patients with mechanical heart support using R.

What I need is adding the following data into the plot (like in the example):

- patients who survived due to a heart transplantation (HTX)
- patients who died

In other words, there are two groups where one is a subset (transplanted patients) of the other (all patients). These two curves must start at 0/0 and will increase.

My own plot is done by:

```
pump <- read.table(file=datafile, header=FALSE,
                   col.names=c('TIME', 'CENSUS', 'DEVICE'))
# convert days to months
pump$TIME <- pump$TIME/(730/24)
mfit.overall <- survfit(Surv(TIME, CENSUS==0) ~ 1, data=pump)
plot(mfit.overall, xlab="months on device", ylab="cum. survival", xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=seq(from=0, to=24, by=6), las=0)
```

How may I add the two additional curves?

Kind Regards
Johann

Sample Kaplan Meier Curve: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/158e8.jpg](http://ars.sciencedirect.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S1053249811007583-gr2.jpg)

Demo Data:

Survival Data, which goes into pump:

> ```
> TIME    CENSUS  DEVICE
> 426     1       1
> 349     1       1
> 558     1       1
> 402     1       1
> 12      0       1
> 84      0       1
> 308     1       1
> 174     1       1
> 315     1       1
> 734     1       1
> 544     1       2
> 1433    1       2
> 1422    1       2
> 262     1       2
> 318     1       2
> 288     1       2
> 1000    1       2
> ```

TX data:

> ```
> TIME    CENSUS  DEVICE
> 426     1        1
> 288     1        2
> 308     1        1
> ```

deaths:

> ```
> TIME    CENSUS  DEVICE
> 12      0        1
> 84      0        1
> ```

Comment: Can you provide the data you use for the plot or dummy data on the same form, in case you cannot share the actual data?

Comment: To be honest, even though `par(new=TRUE)` is a useful hack, I think @Gavin has the better answer. If I had known about it I would also have solved it his way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `par(new=TRUE)` you can draw a second plot in the same figure as the first.

Normally I would recommend using `lines()` for adding curves to a plot, since `par(new=TRUE)` performs the filosophically different task of overlaying plots. When using functions in a way they are not intended to be used you risk commiting misstakes, *e.g.* I nearly forgot the vital `xlim` argument. However, it is not trivial to extract the curves from the `survfit` objects, so I figured it was the lesser of two evils.

```
# Fake data for the plots
pump <- data.frame(TIME=rweibull(40, 2, 20),
                   CENSUS=runif(40) < .3,
                   DEVICE=rep(0:1, c(20,20)))
# load package
library("survival")

# Fit models
mfit.overall <-survfit(Surv(TIME, CENSUS==0) ~ 1, data=pump)
mfit.htx <- survfit(Surv(TIME, CENSUS==0) ~ 1, data=pump, subset=DEVICE==1)

# Plot
plot(mfit.overall, col=1, xlim=range(pump$TIME), fun=function(x) 1-x)
# `xlim` makes sure the x-axis is the same in both plots
# `fun` flips the curve to start at 0 and increase
par(new=TRUE)
plot(mfit.htx, col=2, xlim=range(pump$TIME), fun=function(x) 1-x,
    ann=FALSE, axes=FALSE, bty="n") # This hides the annotations of the 2nd plot
legend("topright", c("All", "HTX"), col=1:2, lwd=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Backlin, Thanks! Yeah, I know that... The point is how to insert the data from 0,0 (lower left corner), which will increase to the upper right corner...

Comment: Backlin,

Perfect! This works! The trick is:

    fun=function(x) 1-x

Comment: There is a `lines()` method so no need to hack the curves out of the survfit object.

Answer (score 7):

No need for `plot.new()` (though this is a nice illustartion of that paradigm). This can all be achieved via the `lines()` method for class `"surfit"`.

```
plot(mfit.overall, col=1, xlim=range(pump$TIME), fun=function(x) 1-x)
lines(mfit.htx, col=2, fun=function(x) 1-x)
lines(mfit.htx, col=2, fun=function(x) 1-x, lty = "dashed", conf.int = "only")
legend("topleft", c("All", "HTX"), col=1:2, lwd=1, bty = "n")
```

This gives, using @Backlin's example data (but different seeds, hence different data)

[image]

The reason for the two calls to `lines()` is to arrange for the confidence interval to be drawn with a dashed line and I couldn't see a way to pass multiple `lty`'s to `lines()` (that worked!) in the single `lines()` call.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know there was a `lines.survfit` function, but this is a better solution than `par(new=TRUE)`.